# Trouble debugging C program in Eclipse on Yosemite

Tags: c, eclipse-cdt

I am getting the following persistent errors trying to debug a C program in Eclipse Juno on my mac:

`Building target: TimeStamps
Invoking: MacOS X C Linker
gcc -v -o "TimeStamps"  ./graphic/arrow.o ./graphic/axesdraw.o . . . 
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.57) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0
Thread model: posix
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.10.0 -o 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [TimeStamps] Error 1`
So, I am confused about how to fix this in Eclipse. The main routing is in timestamp_test.c
I have -g -v as  compiler flags, and -v as a linker flag.
No .o files are made.

Comment: And then if I try to debug it, I just get choices for Java and JUnit tests

Comment: Does `timestamp_test.c` have a `main` function?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the the error given, you need to add the `main` function to `timestamp_test.c`.

Or pass the file that have the `main` function implemented to the compiler.